# magento 2 upgraded issue while runing setup upgrade command Magento_Sales. Original exception message: Warning: Illegal string offsetQ

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Unable to apply data patch

**Magento\Sales\Setup\Patch\Data\ConvertSerializedDataToJson for module Magento_Sales. Original exception message: Warning: Illegal string offset 'option_type' in [Site Path]/vendor/magento/module-sales/Setup/SerializedDataConverter.php on line 33**

anyone can help to get a solution to this above error while running upgrade command. I have upgraded my Magento from 2.2 to 2.3.X.after upgraded I am facing this issue.

Comment: Hey man, Were you able to find anything for this ?

Comment: For this, i had removed vendor after taking backup and reinstall using composer